# menu only showing the first child php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

i have this code:

```
$Maxcount = 10;$count = 1;$query =    "SELECT pages.paid,
     pages.pag_desc,
     pages.isActive,
     pages.pag_pag_id,
    pages.pag_type,
    parent.pag_desc,";while ($count <= $Maxcount) {$query .= "parent".$count.".pag_desc AS parent".$count;if ($count != $Maxcount) {$query .= ", ";$count++;} $query .= " FROM pages ";$query .= "LEFT JOIN pages parent ON pages.pag_pag_id = parent.paid ";$count = 1;while ($count <= $Maxcount) {   if ($count === 1) {
   $query .= "LEFT JOIN pages parent".$count." ON parent.pag_pag_id = parent".$count.".paid "; }else {
   $query .= "LEFT JOIN pages parent".$count." ON parent".($count-1).".pag_pag_id = parent".$count.".paid "  }$count++;}$query .="LEFT JOIN tblgroups_rights_gri on pages.paid = tblgroups_rights_gri.gri_pag_id 
     INNER JOIN users_usergroups on tblgroups_rights_gri.gri_usrg_id = users_usergroups.gid

     WHERE uid = '$uid' AND $where AND pages.isActive=1";

$result = $db->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    $menu = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $menu[] = $row;
    }

}
```

and for showing the menu i used this recursive function :

```
     foreach($menu as $row){
        $x[$row['parent3']][$row['parent2']][$row['parent1']][$row['pag_desc']]=$row['pag_desc'];

    }function recursive($x, $out) { if (is_array($x)){
       //$out .= "<ul>";
       foreach($x as $i => $data) {

           if ($i === '') {
               $out = recursive($data, $out);
               continue;
           }
           $out .= "<li>";
           if (is_array($data)){
               $out .= ' <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
           }
           else
           {
               $out .= '<a href="#">';
           }
           $out .= $i;
           if (is_array($data)){
                $out .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>';
           }
           else
           {
               $out .= "</a>";
           }
           if (is_array($data)){
              $out .= "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
              $out = recursive($data, $out);
              $out .= "</ul></li>";
           }
           else
           {
           $out .= "</li>"; 
           }
       }
       }
    return $out; 
}
```

the result is that its showing only the parent and the first child but in database the child have another child etc...

for example:

parent `user` have a child `admin` and admin have another child called `editor`

but its only showing `user` as a parent and `admin` as a child

any help please? thank u in advance

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#15 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(16) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(164) ["type"]=> int(0) }                         i got this as a result @admcfajn